# Cannot convert from SQLiteCursorLoader to Loader<Cursor>

Tags: android, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock, android-cursorloader, commonsware-cwac

I'm using an activity and a fragment based on ActionBarSherlock. To read rows from an SQLite database I'm trying to use a `Loader` instead of a `ContentProvider`, and I'm trying to get [LoaderEx](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-loaderex) to work for me.

I'm stuck with a stubborn problem: in my fragment's `onCreateLoader` callback, ADT is consistently giving me an error:

```
"Cannot convert from SQLiteCursorLoader to Loader<Cursor>"
```

I'm using the Android v4 Support Library. Because of DEX errors, I've removed `android-support-v4.jar` from both ActionBarSherlock and LoaderEx, and added it into my base project instead. Then I've made both ABS and LoaderEx depend on that.

ABS and LoaderEx are both added as a library project.

I've checked that I'm only using the v4 imports. Also LoaderExDemo compiles and works in an emulator.

These are my fragment's imports:

```
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockListFragment;

import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager;
import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks;
import android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader;
import android.support.v4.content.Loader;

import com.commonsware.cwac.loaderex.SQLiteCursorLoader;
```

Here's my fragment declaration:

```
public class MeetingListFragment 
        extends SherlockListFragment 
        implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {
    private JournalDatabaseHelper db = null;
    private SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = null;
    private SQLiteCursorLoader loader = null;
```

And here's the `getLoader` callback method:

```
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int loaderId, Bundle args) {
    loader = new SQLiteCursorLoader(getSherlockActivity().getApplicationContext(), 
        db, 
        "SELECT _ID, meeting_timestamp, meeting_desc FROM meeting " +
        "ORDER BY meeting_timestamp DESC",
        null);
    return loader;  // <<< this is the line of the ADT/Eclipse error
}
```

I've gone back and forth with this for hours. Some answers on SO are kind of in the area, but no real solutions. What is going wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have:

```
import com.commonsware.cwac.loaderex.SQLiteCursorLoader;
```

That is the wrong `SQLiteCursorLoader`, as that is the one for the native API Level 11+ version of the `Loader` framework. As noted in [the LoaderEx documentation](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-loaderex#packages), you should be using `com.commonsware.cwac.loaderex.acl.SQLiteCursorLoader` if you are using the `Loader` backport from the Android Support package.

Comment: Thank you so much! That was it, of course. I did read the documentation, but it seems I didn't pay close enough attention. Not the first time the support library has complicated things.

Comment: @JereKäpyaho: Yeah, all of us writing libraries are patiently waiting for Gingerbread to fade into the distance. :-)